# Calculating area by classified image in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, area

I want to calculate the area for each classified color in earth engine.
Here are my codes.  [image: here is my imports entries]

```
var image = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA')  
.filterBounds(roi)
.filterDate('2015-01-01', '2015-12-31')
.sort('CLOUD_COVER')
.first());
print(image);  


Map.addLayer(image, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3}, 'image_L8');


var clip = image.clip(table);  //cliping image to shapefile


var newclassified = 
vegetation.merge(water).merge(agri_bare).merge(builtarea);
print(newclassified);
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7', 'B10', 'B11'];


var training = clip.select(bands).sampleRegions({
collection: newclassified,
properties: ['landcover'],
scale: 30
}); 


var classifier = ee.Classifier.cart().train({
features: training,
classProperty: 'landcover',
inputProperties: bands
});

var classified = clip.select(bands).classify(classifier);  

Map.centerObject(newclassified, 11);
Map.addLayer(clip,
{bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.4},
'Landsat image');

Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 1, max: 4, palette: ['green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'red']},
'classification');
```

Now I want to calculate the area covered by green, blue, yellow and red palette.
What code I required to do that??

Comment: Could you include a script link (using the Get Link button) so that others can run your example code? Within the current question content, the 7 variables shown in the screenshot of the Imports section are inaccessible.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fcfc1b242dc959d75bb5e11b98976a44

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To calculate area per class from the image that you classified, you may find the following codes useful. You have to add these codes at the end of your given code.

```
//Select the class from the classified image
var veg = classified.select('classification').eq(1);//vegetation has 1 value in your case

//Calculate the pixel area in square kilometer
var area_veg = veg.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).divide(1000*1000);

//Reducing the statistics for your study area
var stat = area_veg.reduceRegion ({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
  geometry: table,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e9
});

//Get the sq km area for vegetation
print ('Vegetation Area (in sq.km)', stat);
```

You can repeat the same code for other classes. I am not sure how to create a list sequence to get areas for all the classes at the same time. I hope someone will answer that.

Answer (score 7):

To determine the area of each class in a region of interest, first define the region as a geometry:

```js
var roi = ee.Geometry.Point([-113.5911, 37.0855]).buffer(100);
```

and a classified image (with categorical data values):

```js
var class_image = ee.Image('USGS/NLCD/NLCD2011').select('landcover');
```

Then construct a composite image where the first band is the pixel's area and the second band has the class information. Then apply a [grouped reducer](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_grouping) to the composite image, in order to sum all the pixel areas within each class:

```js
var class_areas = ee.Image.pixelArea().addBands(class_image)
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
      groupField: 1,
      groupName: 'code',
    }),
    geometry: roi,
    scale: 1,  // sample the geometry at 1m intervals
    maxPixels: 1e10
  }).get('groups');
```

Finally print out the list of dictionaries containing the calculated areas for each class:

```js
print(class_areas);
```

Here is a link to the complet script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d1f498ae76ed51f305862b2f227c2442