# How do I calculate the pixel areas for the ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram() calculation?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have been following this tutorial: [Reducing Land Cover Data Sets in Earth Engine](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/288012/reducing-land-cover-data-sets-in-earth-engine) , but cannot calculate the pixel values into areas before exporting the tables. I am very new to Google Earth Engine and cannot find the answer elsewhere.

Comment: Welcome @BB88, you should post some code. What you have tried, what you expect, what fails.

Comment: Take a look here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313288/calculating-area-by-classified-image-in-earth-engine